# How to execute selenium test cases from azure devops

Tags: java, selenium, azure-devops, automation, test-plan

I am using Selenium Java for writing automation scripts, also using maven for handling dependencies. and using TestNG to execute test cases. My plan is to Integrate automation with DevOps and trigger automation test cases whenever the latest build is deployed to UAT or any server.

I don't have an Idea how to trigger/execute automation script in azure DevOps. The automation will be headless it will work in the background

Comment: Hi akshay patil; I'm afraid this question is much too broad for this site. What you need to do is to read up on the ways you can [UI test with Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops) in azure pipelines, **try it out** and ask *specific* questions here if you run into specific problems.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I will check it out, also the above article is for .Net not Java

Answer (score 0):

This Article can be useful for you
https://medium.com/@kiranreddy365/how-to-run-selenium-tests-using-maven-through-command-line-f4f48b37aba4

Step 2.d explains running tests through command line, use the same command line in your azure devops pipeline script task to execute tests as part of your pipeline. Of course the pipeline yaml should be present in the same git repo where tests are kept!

Comment: I will check it out

Comment: did the link help?